# Unable to call web api methods

Tags: angularjs, web, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am developing small application in web api2 with angularjs. I have one controller called UsersController with index action method and index view. I am using angularjs. Inside script folder i have one more folder users with three files modules.js,controller.js and service.js. Also i have one more web api controller called TestController with all http methods inside. I am calling test controller as below using angularjs. In index.cshtml i have form to submit simple data.

```
this.saveUsers = function (users) {
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            data: users,
            url: "/api/Test",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    }
```

When i click on submit button i am getting error message as below.

> `http://localhost:22499/Users/api/Test`
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

n my url I am getting Users(Controllername MVC). I am not sure why it is not calling and May i know is this is the reason that i am not able to call any http methods? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Whether the content (users) that you are trying to pass is a JSON ?

Comment: Thank you. Yes i am trying to pass data as json.

Comment: Based on the error it says It didn't find the URL or the service that you are trying to hit, check if the URL is correct.

Comment: I am calling  url: "/api/Test". where test is web api controller.

Comment: Yes I understand you are trying to hit http://localhost:22499/Users/api/Test but the server says it didnt find anything matching this URL

Comment: Users is mvc controller name. Is this required to call web api controller?

Comment: First hit the URL (http://localhost:22499/Users/api/Test)  in your browser and see if you get a response.

Comment: I am not getting any response. Url not found error i am getting.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your URL,  I am not sure what's the expectation on the service side, try the URL without the Users (http://localhost:22499/api/Test) and check

Comment: I think  this should be the format for the URL
$http.post('api/' + ControllerName + '/' + methodName)

Comment: yes but i am calling /api/Test. I have not included Users anywhere.

Comment: Please check my previous comment 
I think this should be the format for the URL $http.post('api/' + ControllerName + '/' + methodName) 

Do not use / in the beginning